# Mass SNMP updates?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, snmp

Is there an easy way to update over 1000 Windows hosts with an additional permitted manager? I have tools to remotely run scripts on hosts, but it is a little bit difficult to filter out specific hosts, and you end up having to type each hostname into the program then add it to a list of hosts to run the script on. I have scripts that will update permitted managers, and other SNMP settings in the registry; but I need a better way to run the script on multiple hosts. Does anyone know of an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you just put the list of servers in a text file and delete the ones that you don't want it to run on. Then just use `psexec`'s `@file` feature to feed the list of servers to psexec. It will then iterate through the list of servers, running the specified command(s) on each.

Or, even better, put all of the machines in an AD security group and use Group Policy Preferences Registry Settings to push the change out to the servers. You can use Item Level Targeting to apply it only to servers in the specified security group. When new servers get spun up, just make including them in this group part of the provisioning process.